# Fullscreen Flash Video breaks in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.1 in FireFox

Tags: video, flash

I've ran into an issue that completely breaks Video in FireFox version 31. On the Gaming Live Stream Platform Twitch.TV for example, I can full screen the video one time, then close it back to standard size with no problem. The issue arises when I go to full screen the video again. The video will not fullscreen, and the video will freeze, however audio will continue to play. If I un-maximize the FireFox window the video feed glitches completely, once again, audio keeps playing. Is there any fix for this or is this a bug plaguing FireFox.

Edit: Ive Tried running Chromium and Chrome, but Maximizing either window breaks the image of the window.

Edit 2:  Ive tested this in Unity, KDE and XFCE the issue seems to be in Gnome Shell itself